# Terraform Show changes in IAM permission for user in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

I am trying to add Users and Groups in a gcp project via terraform.
I have used following as an example:

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "this" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/serviceusage.apiKeysAdmin"
  members = ["group:adminapi@example.com"]
}
```

I am running this in loop so its able to add multiple users and groups.

However, when user or group is added and their permission modified, say they have been given additional permission like `roles/ml.developer` manually, terraform plan isn't showing any diff in role added.

Is there any other resource I should be using for this scenario? Note: I have used google_project_iam_member resource as well but with same result as google_project_iam_binding.

Comment: It looks like something else is changing your IAM outside of Terraform. To make sure, you can try to delete a binding manually and doing a new plan.
If not, can you share how you implemented your loop ?

Comment: @Lauden Yes, IAM permission being changed outside but terraform plan isn't showing diff for the changes permissions against user/group

Answer (score 0):

If the config is being changed somewhere else, then it's normal. Terraform doesn't check the entire object you're creating when refreshing. You will need to import the changes outside terraform with a `terraform import` to be able to manage it with Terraform.

This depends on how provider are coded, they rather have fine grain controls on what is controlled with Terraform and if a role is creating with some other tools, ex : Organization policies or some other Terraform project it won't collid every time.